# Cannot open external URL on Android device using ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to build an android app. I have an element with ng-click which calls a function doing the following:

```
$window.open(encodeURI(url), '_system', 'location=yes');
```

This should open the device's default browser with the url. Yet when I run this on an Android device and click the element nothing happens. I have hooked up a debugger and still get no errors in the console and definitely execute that line.

Comment: if you run in web what is happening?

Comment: Did you do
`cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git`
?

Comment: Works fine in the browser. I have not tried the plugin, hopefully that's it, I will give that a shot.

Comment: @BotanMan That was my problem, so simple! thanks, add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

`cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inapp‌​browser.git`

And here we are!